# Afrikaans kids' book about an abducted girl

Tags: identification-request, afrikaans-language

I'm looking for help on finding a book that I read in Afrikaans around, a short (20-30 pages) hardcover kids' book. I got it from my grandparents 2012-2013. It's about a girl, 6-10 years old, white with blond hair. She gets abducted on a pavement. It was illustrated in an oil painting style and only has a few words on each page. I'm not sure if it was originally published in Afrikaans or if it's a translation.

Comment: I remember that she was abducted on a pavement. I read this book in 2012-2013, and the cover is the type of style you get in most short kids' books, kind of hard, but not many pages. The girl was white, probably 6-10 years old, with blonde hair. I got it from my grandparents at their house, they've searched but can't remember the title/author nor where it is

Comment: Are you using the British, or one of the North American meanings of Pavement? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pavement#Noun